# async delete from DB using Django 4.2 with adelete()

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, async-await

As per docs since v4.2 Django comes with async version of delete method named `adelete()`. But I do not understand how to delete an object from DB using it.

```
db_object = await DbModel.objects.aget(pk=module_id)
await db_object.adelete() # doesn't work
```

It fails with an error:
`"AttributeError: 'DbModel' object has no attribute 'adelete'`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**adelete** is a queryset method, not a method on the model.

So you can't delete single object using adelete.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#deleting-objects

try this

```
await DbModel.objects.filter(pk=module_id).adelete()
```